# Text on StyledLabel being truncated

Tags: java, swing, awt, swt

All, thanks in advance for all assistance.

I am mixing some SWT and swing. Here is the code:

```
Composite sessionComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT_EMBEDDED | SWT_BORDER);
sessionComposite.setLayout(0,0,64,64);

Frame frame = new Frame(sessionComposite);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(Flowlayout.LEFT)));
frame.add(panel);


StyledLabel btnClearHistory = new StyledLabel("Clear Session History"); 

// some mouse listeners etc...

panel.add(btnClearHistory);
```

All works well except the  only thing that displays on the button is "Clear Sessio" the rest is truncated.

I have tried setting `preferredSize` on the Panel, Frame and Label but nothing works..
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because you are explicitly setting the `Composite`'s size to 64x64. You should use a `Layout` instead. Please read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Comment: I have tried removing that but it still does not work.

Comment: So you now use a layout?

Comment: Which layout would you  suggest? And on which component? The Composite, Label, Frame or Panel?  Only the Layout that you see in this code. You see that is where confusion comes in.

Comment: Never tried mixing gui frameworks (that's devil's work :) ), but the type of layout depends on how your gui should look like. In this example I would start with `sessionComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout())`. The see what happens. Why do you have to mix them anyway?

Comment: I have also tried Rowlayout but it kept crashing my application.

Comment: I will try that now. Had to mix styles because I could not get the button I was using to undeline during the mouseHover event.

Comment: I'll try yo come up with an example. What's `StyledLabel` anyway? Doesn't seem to be part of the standard API.

Comment: sessionComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout()) - failed, no text is displayed on the StyledLabel. StyledLabel - com.jodisoft.swing.StyledLabel.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile at all. In addition, you need to use `SWT_AWT.new_Frame(Composite)` to create an embedded Frame.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Composite sessionComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.BORDER);

    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(sessionComposite);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    frame.add(panel);

    JButton button = new JButton("Clear Session History"); 
    panel.add(button);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400,200);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: My code compiles and executes I am just having issues seeing the entire text in the StyledLabel. The text truncates at "Clear Sessio" I cannot modify my parent composite, so I cannot change its layout.

Comment: @MichealNoel `sessionComposite.setLayout(0,0,64,64);` doesn't compile, `SWT_EMBEDDED` and `SWT_BORDER` aren't defined, `Flowlayout.LEFT` should be `FlowLayout.LEFT`...  Did you try my code?

Comment: I do have "SWT_AWT.new_Frame(Composite)", just a typo. And everything compiles. I wish I could copy/paste my code into this thread but I am on two separate/environments  machines.

Comment: Your code looks like my code. The things you said that are missing I have it in the code just didn't type it in becuase I cannot copy and paste

Comment: Ok thanks. I cannot send a screenshot because of the separation of environs. I cannot change the layout of my parent composite because its already cready and is populated with other components. All I need is for my panel to stretch to hold the label.

Comment: @MichealNoel Well, without your actual code (*the same code*), there really isn't much I/we can do.

Comment: That looks good. The only difference is that I need a  btn/label that performs like a hyperling and will change color/undeline when the mouse hovers over it.